# Interview: on People Matching

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I saw this interview question recently for a firm that said:

> Group of people, you can call `Know(i, j)` to ask if `i`th person knows `j`th, the return value is `true` (`i` knows `j`) or `false` (`i` does not know `j`). Find the person that everybody else knows him but he knows nobody.

I can think of a `O(N^2)` implementation such that you just match every person with the method with every other person, eliminating anyone who actually knows someone. I however cannot think of a faster implementation than this.

Can anyone help or give hints?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can do this in linear time with a simple algorithm. In two lookups, we can eliminate at least one candidate -- pick two persons, and remove person `i` with `Know(i,j)` or `~Know(j,i)`.

Comment: What if there are N people and none of them know each other? In that case complexity becomes O(N^2) no?

Comment: @ElKamina: The complexity will still be O(N). For each pair of persons, since neither knows each other we remove both of them. The problem description has a valid person always existing, but we can easily handle the case where there may not be such a person by checking at the end after identifying the final candidate.

Answer (score 2):

All we have to do is -

1. Find out a person who doesn't know anyone else
2. And then check everyone knows that person

**Step 1:** Find out a person who doesn't know anyone else.
Initially every one is our candidate. So let's start with any one i as current node. Iterate over all candidates j. If Knows(i, j) is false. Then j cannot be our candidate. So remove j from candidates. If Knows(i, j) is true for any j, then i cannot be our candidate, so current node will be updated to j, and remove node i. Repeat this until we can't update current node. The last current node is our final candidate. This will be actually O(N) because at each step we are actually removing one node, either i or j.

**Step 2:** We found a person who doesn't know anyone else. But we've to verify that everyone else knows him. What we can just do is iterate over all the nodes and check, which is O(N). If we found that this is not our node, then there is no such solution. Because there cannot be another node k, which is the solution, as i doesn't know k.

We can use a link list for storing the list of candidates so that removing a candidate will be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

```
while there are at least two candidate people remaining:
    if Know(i, j) then
        i is not the solution - remove from list of candidates
    else
        j is not the solution - remove from list of candidates
```

last (wo)man standing is the solution....

If the data structures in use don't make it clear how to "remove" a candidate, a loop over an array can be used:

```
int candidate = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    if (know(candidate, i))
        candidate = i;
// candidate now holds the solution...
```